# Ошибка при распознавании речи

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vista

Использую компонент `DirectSR`, импортированный как ActiveX, также SAPI 5.3, 4.0. 
Все сделал как здесь: [Технологии распознавания речи в Delphi с использованием Microsoft Speech API](http://cybern.ru/texnologii-raspoznavaniya-rechi-v-delphi-s-ispolzovaniem-microsoft-speech-api.html)

Но проект выдает ошибку: "Отказано в доступе".
Имею Vista SP1, Delphi XE2. 
Скажите, в чем проблема? Может, кто-нибудь знает.
Даже в проектах с простым распознаванием такая же ошибка.